# button queues its click events instead of disabling it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, button

I change my button's "**Enabled**" *property* to "**false**" but my button still catches it's click *event*. I put *Thread.Sleep()* method to imitate some process. While my button is greyed out, i click on it, and after current process is done it begins work again (because i clicked on it while it was greyed out)

Here's my code:

```
    int i = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "0";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //first click
        button1.Enabled = false;
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(3000);           //if i click twice more while button is greyed-out the app will be non-responsive for 9 second and then prints "3" to my label
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

How can i disable my button completely (not allowing it's *events* to rise, but visible)?

Comment: You are freezing the UI thread for 3 seconds every time you click the button.

Comment: You trying to disable the button in its click event at which point your event has already been raised. You should try diasabling it in your Form1 ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are freezing the UI thread which prevent anything from happening UI-wise. You should considering using the TPL to do such work.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //first click
    button1.Enabled = false;

    i++;

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

    label1.Text = i.ToString();
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This works, Thanks! Sorry if it's stupid question but if my UI is freezing, how come it perceives my clicks?

Comment: @HüseyinMerkit There are a lot resources around explaining the concepts behind the UI thread. To be brief and not accurate, all the interactions on controls (clicks etc) are managed by one dedicated thread. For instance, when you click on the button, the button1_click method is called on that thread. But then if you block this thread, like you are with a Thread.Sleep in the method, the application will not be able to process any other inputs until the thread is unblocked.

Answer (score 2):

The Thread.Sleep(3000) call is blocking the function so the button doesn't get disabled. A quick and dirty fix to this is to call `Application.DoEvents();` directly after `button1.Enabled = false;`. This forces the application to process any waiting events and should ensure that the button is disabled.

If you plan to replace Thread.Sleep(3000) with a long running process then you should use a BackgroundWorker. You'll find it under Components in the designer Toolbox.